# bash delete if pattern1 and pattern2 found using sed

Tags: bash, sed, pattern-matching

I need to delete all the lines in a file that have two separate keywords

example file:

```
2  563587992014-01-26      2014-01-26T09:45:53     DC  14003 5         3.60
2  563589242014-01-26      2014-01-26T10:03:13     DC  14003 6         4.80
2  563589252014-01-26      2014-01-26T10:03:20     DC  14002 2         5.50
2  563589272014-01-26      2014-01-26T10:03:34     DC  14002 3         3.30
```

I want to delete all lines that have 'DC' and '14003'.

I am experimenting with sed

```
var1="DC"
var2="14003"

sed -i /$var1/$var2/d /path/file
```

but it doesn't work. can anyone help ?

Comment: sed /pattern1/pattern2/d is not a valid sed instruction but a miw of 2. s/p1/p2/ that substitute p1 by p2 and /p1/ action that execute the action if p1 is found (d is your action in your line but sed take $var2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk` for this, it is quite simpler:

```
$ awk '$5 != 14003 && $4~/DC/' file
2  563589252014-01-26      2014-01-26T10:03:20     DC  14002 2         5.50
2  563589272014-01-26      2014-01-26T10:03:34     DC  14002 3         3.30
```

To have the file updated, you have to redirect the output to a new file. Then you can replace the former with the new one with `mv`:

```
awk '$5 != 14003 && $4~/DC/' file > new_file && mv new_file file
```

Comment: doesn't work, or am I doing it wrong !?

$Serie="14003"
awk '$5 != $Serie && $4~/DC/' /home/etc/vartotals.tot

Comment: @PedroCaldeira works for me.  What result do you get.

Comment: the file stays the same, no lines were deleted

Comment: @PedroCaldeira se my updated post on how to use variable with `awk`  `awk -v="$var1" 'some code use v'` or `awk 'some code use v' v="$var1"`

Comment: @PedroCaldeira to have the file updated, you have to redirect the output: `awk '$5 != 14003 && $4~/DC/' file > new_file`.

Comment: @PedroCaldeira What do you get? It is difficult to guess.

Comment: just another question.
And if I want to write to the file all Var1=DC but Var2 <> "14003" ?

Comment: @PedroCaldeira isn't it what you asked the first time?

Comment: No, I have asked to delete the lines that contains var1 AND var2
now I also need to get all these lines instead of deleting them.
and to get the first 10 chars of each one.

Comment: @PedroCaldeira this is a different question, so it'd better to [Ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '/14003/{/DC/d}'
```

this does:

> delete all lines that have 'DC' and '14003'.

if you use sed with shell variable, use double-quotes:

```
sed "...$FOO...$BAR.."
```

Comment: I am using:

    if [ $Series = "1" ]; then
       sed /$Serie/{/DC/d} /home/etc/somefile
    else
       ...
    fi

Comment: @PedroCaldeira I clearly wrote in answer, if you want to use shell variables in sed, quote the sed expression with double quotes.

Comment: Yes you did, that would mean :
sed "/$var1/{/$var2/d}" /path/file
is that it ?

Comment: It works like this :
sed -i /$Serie/DC/d /home/winrest/files/data/fdochash.000

Comment: @PedroCaldeira I don't know if you typed the double quotes. anyway, point is it works for you. then good.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk '!/DC/ || !/14003/' file
2  563589252014-01-26      2014-01-26T10:03:20     DC  14002 2         5.50
2  563589272014-01-26      2014-01-26T10:03:34     DC  14002 3         3.30
```

---

Using variable:

```
var1="DC"
var2="14003"
awk '$0!~v1 || $0!~v2' v1="$var1" v2="$var2" file
2  563589252014-01-26      2014-01-26T10:03:20     DC  14002 2         5.50
2  563589272014-01-26      2014-01-26T10:03:34     DC  14002 3         3.30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use perl for this:

```
perl -i -lne 'print unless(/DC/ and  /14003/)' your_file
```

Note: This will do in place replacement.

If you wish to include this in a shell script, then below is the way to do it:

```
#!/bin/ksh

one="DC"
two="14003"
three=`perl -i -lne "print unless(/$one/ and /$two/)" temp`
```